# GET request works in Postman but not in NodeJS using request package

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios, request-promise

I've been trying to migrate a simple web scraping script to NodeJS using `request-promise` package but I'm always getting the following error as output

```
403 This IP has been automatically blocked
```

However, if I use my browser or Postman to trigger the request it works perfectly (and the IP is not blocked at all)

Here's the code I'm using for NodeJS

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const main = async () => {
    const options = {
        url: 'https://sfbay.craigslist.org/d/software-qa-dba-etc/search/sof',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }
    }
    try {
        const htmlResult = await request.get(options);
        console.log(htmlResult);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

}

main();
```

I've also tried with Axios, but the output is the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at the red box at the top of https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise (not the cause of your problem, but something better solved now rather than after you've done any more work with that module).

Comment: You should use PROXY service like [BrightData](https://brightdata.com/)